# Yii2 session event before close/destroy

Tags: session, events, yii2

I want to run some code every time before user session is being destroyed for **any** reason. I haven't found any events binded to session in official documentation. Has anyone found a workaround about this?

Comment: You can create your own and trigger it. See [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-events.html).

Comment: Well, in that case, the question is how would I attach it to the session#close or session#destroy...

Comment: How about overriding `yii\web\Session` component, modifying it with events and replacing its class in application config? The basic idea is calling parent implementation in overrided methods and then trigger your events.

Comment: Afraid that's a little bit too hardcore for me. But assuming I'd go that way, what would I have to do in order to override this?

Comment: You can simply post in answers, if you want...

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best solution (maybe better exist), that's why I didn't post it as answer.

Comment: Well, I think, it's certainly working solution.

Comment: Issued this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no events out of the box for Session component.

You can solve this problem with overriding core `yii\web\Session` component.

1) Override `yii\web\Session` component:

```
<?php

namespace app\components;

use yii\web\Session as BaseSession

class Session extends BaseSession
{
    /**
     * Event name for close event
     */
    const EVENT_CLOSE = 'close';

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function close()
    {
        $this->trigger(self::EVENT_CLOSE); // Triggering our custom event first;
        parent::close(); // Calling parent implementation
    }
}
```

2) Apply your custom component to application config:

```
'session' => [
    'class' => 'app\components\Session' // Passing our custom component instead of core one
],
```

3) Attach handler with one of available methods:

```
use app\components\Session;
use yii\base\Event;

Event::on(Session::className(), Session::EVENT_OPEN, function ($event) {
    // Insert your event processing code here
});
```

Alternatively you can specify handler as method of some class, check [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-events.html).

As an alternative to this approach, take a look at this [extension](https://github.com/lisachenko/go-aop-php). I personally didn't test it. The Yii way to do it I think will be overriding with adding and triggering custom events as I described above.

Comment: @arogachev Why session events are not supported in Yii2? Will it be supported in the future?